# Getting the databound value from repeater control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

As a follow up to my question  [Looping through a repeater control to get values of Textbox in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043829/looping-through-a-repeater-control-to-get-values-of-textbox-in-asp-net)
If user has entered a a quantity in the textbox, I want to get the corresponding ProductID value from the repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptRequestForm" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:50%" class="TextFontBold"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Supply Name"></asp:Label></td>
                                    <td style="width:25%" class="TextFontBold"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text="Quantity"></asp:Label></td>
                                    <td style="width:25%" class="TextFontBold"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text="Price (ea.)"></asp:Label></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:50%" class="TextFont"><asp:Label ID="lblProductName" Text="<%#Trim(Eval("Product_Title"))%>" ><%#Trim(Eval("Supplie_title"))%></asp:Label></td>
                                    <td style="width:25%"><asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" Width="30%" onblur="Javascript:numberonly(this)"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                    <td style="width:25%" class="TextFont"><span><%#Trim(FormatCurrency(Eval("Price")))%></span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

My codebehind is:

```
For Each item As RepeaterItem In rptRequestForm.Items
                txtField = item.FindControl("txtBox")
                If Not IsNothing(txtField) Then
                    j += 1
                    strText = strText & ", " & txtField.Text
                End If
Next
```

I am using FindControl to loop through the textbox (to see if user has entered a valid quantity). How can I get the value of the corresponding ProductID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a label to your ItemTemplate, like this:

```
<td style="width:50%" class="TextFont"><asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server"><%#Trim(Eval("Product_Title"))%></asp:Label></td>
```

And in your code behind, find it like this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    TextBox txtField = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtBox");

    //extract value from textbox
    int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)item.FindControl("txtBox").Text);

    //extract the value from the label
    string productName = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblProductName")).Text;
}
```

Comment: your suggestion would get me ALL the productID values (even the ones where the user has not enetered a quantity), correct?

Comment: How so? You would be grabbing the value of the product name label from a single item (Repeater1.Items[0]).

Comment: I updated the posting with my codebehind. I am doing a For Each loop on "item As RepeaterItem In rptRequestForm.Items".

Comment: on your line: Label lblProdTitle = (Label)item.FindControl("lblProductName"); ..... I get error message "Value of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' cannot be converted to 'String'"

Comment: if I change strProduct = item.FindControl("lblProductTitle") to be strProduct = item.FindControl("lblProductTitle").ToString() .......then I get an error message on "productName = lblProdTitle.Text" saying "'text' is not a member of 'String'"

Comment: Yea, because you need to cast it as a label. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: does not work. I get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In your example, you are doing item.FindControl("lblProductTitle"), but my example is item.FindControl("lblProductName"). Please make sure that the IDs match up and try again.

Comment: Did you add the product name label in your item template, like in my example? This definitely works, so there's something missing from your code.

Comment: do you mean ID="lblProductName" ? If so, yes

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code that you're using now?

Comment: You didn't add the runat="server" to lblProductName. You might also need to wrap the text property of the label in single quotes instead of double quotes, since your Eval() function needs double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `ProductId` in a `hidden field` in the repeater ItemTemplate. Then You can access the Product Id in the same way, as you are accessing the quantity using `FindControl`

Comment: using FindControl will return all the ProductID values, even the ones without a valid quantity, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're worried about getting product names where there is no quantity, then just evaluate before you assign.  For example (based on @James' code), you just add `IF Quantity > 0 THEN ...` before you do `string productName = ...`

A couple of changes I'd make to that code, though...

1) check for the object to exist before you attempting to convert it to a textbox.  For example, `IF NOT item.FindControl("txtBox") is NOTHING...`

2) check for a null condition before you attempt `convert.toint32()`.  for example, `IF NOT string.isnullorempty(txtField)...`

3) When you do the Quantity variable assignment, you don't need FindControl, because you already found it (and assigned it to your txtField variable).  So just `int Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtField.Text);`