# Changing an asp:label text inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have this label inside a repeater

```
<asp:Label id="lblsub" runat=server text="sdds" />
```

I am trying to change the text of this label,this is the code behind

```
 For Each Item As RepeaterItem In dg.Items
    Dim l As New label
        l = CType(Item.FindControl("lblsub"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)
        l.text="test"
    Next
```

unfortunately this code doesn't work for me ,the text value doesn't change ,so I will be very happy to some help here

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer in this question. Believe it will solve your issue.

[Getting the databound value from repeater control in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066096/getting-the-databound-value-from-repeater-control-in-asp-net/7066193#7066193)

EDIT

First of all, make sure you always use quotes in your markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblsub" runat="server" Text="sdds" />
```

Try something like this in your code behind. Forgive me if my VB is a little rusty:

```
For Each Item As RepeaterItem in dg.Items
    Dim l As Label = CType(Item.FindControl("lblsub"), Label)
    l.Text = "test"
Next
```

There were just a couple little problems with syntax. I don't know if they are causing your issue, but best get the easy stuff out of the way first.

Comment: not sure my friend what to look in your answer,I didn't see how to change the text of the label

Comment: I am getting null with your code too:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: At what point are you trying to change the text? Can you move the code to the ItemDataBound event? This approach definitely works, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: thanks james ,you right this need to happen inside itemdatabound:  Sub R1_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
  
  For Each Item As RepeaterItem In dg.Items
    Dim l As  label
        l = directcast(e.Item.FindControl("lblsub"), label)
  
  if l isnot Nothing  then
  
  l.text="dsd"
  
  end if
        
    Next 

  
  end sub

Comment: I don't think so. By the way, when you're inside of the ItemDataBound event, don't use a loop. Just use e.Item.FindControl("lblsub")

Answer (score 2):

When is that bit of code being ran?

Make sure you are not rebinding the repeater afterwards by doing the following in your `Page_Load`:

```
Sub Page_load
   If not Page.IsPostBack Then
      BindRepeater()
   End If
End Sub
```

If you need to do this bit of code every time the repeater is bound, then put your code into the DataBound event:

```
Protected Sub dg_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles dg.ItemDataBound
   Select Case e.item.itemtype
       Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
    Dim l As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblsub")
    l.Text = "foo"
   End Select
End Sub
```

I haven't got any programming software with me so unsure of the syntax

Comment: I tried your code but I getting null :System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I've made a change to the code to not include header/footer, which i think is whats causing the null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

C# code sample (it should be inside method or page_load)

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rt in MyRepeater.Items)
            {
                Label l = ((Label)rt.FindControl("lblPrice"));
                l.Text = "200";
            }
```